I install pandas but "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'" error

MacBook Air M2
Visual Studio Code
Python 3.12.3

I installed pandas using
pip3 install pandas

and I wite code
import pandas as pd

If i run this code there is an error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

There is no error before I run the code,
But If I run the code error exist.
Also numpy has same error.
I installed it but can't find module...

Does this answer your question? Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module? I'd look at Brett Cannon's answer first; he's a Python dev.

VSCode might create a python env apart from your local python. Check if the interpreter used by VSCode and the one you are using on terminal are the same.
To check the terminal one, use python -V or python --version
To check which interpreter VSCode is using:

Use the shortcut Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P
Type: >python: select interpreter
Select, from the list, the same one that you installed and are using on the terminal.

This should solve the problem.

When I use python -V it says "Python 3.9.6"
But I install pandas in Python 3.12.3
So use ">python: select interpreter" to change "Python 3.12.3".
After I change interpreter, The result of "python -V" is still Python 3.9.6
Is python interpreter did not changed?

@user24723398 - what do you see in the status bar of the vscode ? It should say the interpreter that is currently being selected.

When i select interpreter, status bar didn’t say anything. Is Interpreter did not changed? After that i type python -V status still says python 3.9.6 (oppose selected interpreter)

I sovled it.
When I command python -V it always say python 3.9.6 even I changed vsCode python Interpreter.
So I specify /path of python 3.9.6 -m pip install pandas and it works!
But I just wonder How to change my python interpreter?
I use vsCode >python:select interpreter to change my python.
But I think in didn't work.
